# How can I use UTF-8 string as char* in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, visual-studio-2015, utf-8

I need to create a library which will expose some C APIs.

```
get_ble_list(char **deviceNames);
```

Here I use another third party library to get the list of Bluetooth devices which returns the device name as CAtlStringW.
Now I need to convert this into normal C character array which I am able to do. But when it comes to non ASCII, Unicode characters, I didn't get an expected result. 
Eg: I set the Bluetooth name on my mobile as മലയാളം. But I got ??? as the output on my test GUI app which uses my library.

Comment: How are the strings encoded? Do the GUI handle that encoding?

Comment: It's actually really rather difficult to handle UTF-8 (a naive conversion to char[] is a non-starter) although I'm sure you'll find a library if you dig around for long enough. See http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Windows APIs don't play nicely with UTF-8. You need to transcode it to UTF-16 (with `wchar_t` as the target type) to do anything with it (note: transcoding involves allocating memory for the result and calling a function, *not* casting to the target type).

Comment: @Bathsheba no, utfcpp won't do anything useful here.

Answer (score 1):

The source string is `CStringW`, not `CAtlStringW` which is a base class. Use `CA2W` and `CW2A` to convert between UTF8 and UTF16.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <atlstr.h>//Visual Studio specific

...
CStringA utf8 = CW2A(L"മലയാളം", CP_UTF8);
CStringW utf16 = CA2W(utf8, CP_UTF8);
MessageBoxW(0, utf16, 0, 0);
```

You can cast `utf8` to `const char*`. Or cast `utf16` to `const wchar_t*`.

This is not a writable buffer. Don't cast either `CAtlStringW` or `CStringW` to `wchar_t*`, and certainly not `char*` which is completely wrong.

For writable buffer, use `CString::GetBuffer`/`CString::ReleaseBuffer` method. Or allocate new buffer to pass. Make sure the source compiles with zero warnings.

You can switch to UTF16 if the C APIs are used exclusively by Windows. Use `wchar_t` instead of `char`, use "wide C string" version of C functions, example `wcscpy` instead of `strcpy`.

```
void get_ble_list(wchar_t **deviceNames)
{
    ...
    wcscpy(...);
}
```